# Cherrypy and Pyramid integration

Tags: pyramid, wsgi, cherrypy

I have a pyramid application running under apache using mod_wsgi.
I am planning to migrate from apache to cherrypy. 
I am able to load static page of the existing web application with cherrypy. However for any AJAX request, I am getting resource not found (404) error. 
Any clues??

Thanks

30-Mar-2016

Here is code structure

```
MyProject   
   |
cherry_wsgi.py (creates wsgi app object)
cherry_server.py (starts cherrypy server using app object from cherry_wsgi.py)  
development.ini
myproject
   |
    __init__.py  (Scans sub-folders recursively)
    views.py
    mydata
       |
        __init__.py 
        data
          |
          __init__.py  (Added route for getdata)
          views.py (implementation of getdata)
  |
myclient
    |
    index.html (AJAX query)
```

Contents of myclient/index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>HOME UI</title>
   </head>          
   <body>
     <button id="submit">Give it now!</button>
     <script src="./jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
     <script>$("#submit").on('click', function() 
    {
       $.ajax(
      {
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      url: "../myproject/data/getdata",
      success: function (data) 
      {
         console.log("LED On" );
      },
      error: function ()
      {
          console.error("ERROR");
       }
   });
});</script></body></html>
```

File `myproject/__init__.py`

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.renderers import JSONP
import os 
import logging

def includeme(config):
   """ If include function exists, write this space.
   """
   pass

def main(global_config, **settings):
   """ This function returns a Pyramid WSGI application."""
   config = Configurator(settings=settings)
   config.add_renderer('jsonp', JSONP(param_name='callback'))
   config.include(includeme)

   directory = "/home/redmine/Downloads/MyProject/myproject/mydata/"
   for root,dir,files in os.walk(directory):
      if root == directory:# Walk will return all sublevels. 
        for dirs in dir: #This is a tuple so we need to parse it
          config.include('myproject.mydata.' + str(dirs), route_prefix='/' + str(dirs))

config.add_static_view('static', 'prototype', cache_max_age=3600)
config.scan()
return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

File `myproject/views.py`

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
```

File `myproject/mydata/__init__.py`

```
import data
```

File `mproject/mydata/data/__init__.py`

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator

def includeme(config):
   config.add_route('get_data', 'getdata', xhr=True)

def main(global_config, **settings):
   print 'hello'
   config = Configurator(settings=settings)
   config.include(includeme, route_prefix='/data')
   config.add_static_view('static', 'prototype', cache_max_age=3600)
   config.scan('data')
   return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

File `mproject/mydata/data/views.py`

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
import json

@view_config(route_name='get_data', xhr=True, renderer='jsonp')
def get_data(request):
  return "{'firstName' : 'John'}"
```

File `cherry_wsgi.py`

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.paster import get_app

config = Configurator()
app = get_app('development.ini', 'main')
```

File `cherry_server.py`

```
from cherry_wsgi import app
import cherrypy

conf = {
     '/': {
         'tools.sessions.on': True,
         'tools.staticdir.root': '/home/redmine/Downloads/MyProject/'
     },
     '/myclient': {
         'tools.staticdir.on': True,
         'tools.staticdir.dir': './myclient'
     }
 }


if __name__ == '__main__':
   cherrypy.tree.mount(app, "/", conf) 
   cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()
   server = cherrypy._cpserver.Server()
   server.socket_host = "0.0.0.0"
   server.socket_port = 9090
   server.thread_pool = 30

   server.subscribe()
   cherrypy.engine.start()
   cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Comment: Are you just using cherrypy's wsgi server for your Pyramid app? That's the only Pyramid/cherrypy integration that I have done.

Comment: Yes. I am using cherrypy's wsgi server for pyramid. I followed this article https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-python-wsgi-applications-using-a-cherrypy-web-server-behind-nginx (Note that I have not used nginx yet but planning to use it in near future. As of now only cherrypy.)

Comment: Here is an example how I setup my Pyramid apps on Openshift. There are examples of the setup of using waitress and cherrypy in the App.py file. Hth.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264103/how-to-create-app-using-pyramid-into-openshift/27324518#27324518

Comment: I would be good if you posted your ajax code as well as your pyramid view.py code.  We can go for there.

Comment: Post and format your code in your question not here in the comments.

Comment: Post the relevant view.py code also.

Comment: @fat fantasma,Thank you for suggestions. I have placed relevant code in question section.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I caught everything but I did see a couple of bugs.  First off, your url was off in your ajax call.  Next in your views.py you were using jsonp and not json as your renderer. Also, you were using "route_name"  instead of "route" (ajax calls) for the @view_config.  Finally, you were returning a string. I changed it to a dict.

Pyramid can be tricky if you don't set up your project structure in a straight forward way.  I learned the hard way :)

**Contents of myclient/index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HOME UI</title>
    </head>          
<body>
 <button id="submit">Give it now!</button>
 <script src="./jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
 <script>$("#submit").on('click', function() 
{
   $.ajax(
  {
  type: "GET",
  async: false,
  url: "getdata",
  success: function (data) 
  {
     console.log("LED On" );
  },
  error: function ()
  {
      console.error("ERROR");
   }
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**File mproject/mydata/data/views.py**

```
from pyramid.view import view_config

@view_config(name='get_data',  renderer='json')
def get_data(request):
    return {'firstName' : 'John'}
```

Now after looking at you overall file structure it does not look like a standard pyramid app.  You have a lot of things going and it looks like over programming to me. There is a lot of duplicate code. Maybe you are doing this for a reason but I don't know.

I included below a pyramid start git repo.  I built it to help people get started putting there pyramid projects on Openshift.  I would think your pyramid project should follow the same outline.  No need for deep folders.

The file you want to pay particular close attention to is the "app.py.disabled" file.  Don't mind the disabled part. There are two ways to start an Openshift pyramid app and this git repo is using the wsgi.py file.  You can just switch the two.

Anyway,  inside the app.py.disabled file you can see all the different ways that I have used to setup pyramid app using wsgi servers (simple, waitress, and cherrypy).  Just uncomment/comment out the code you want.

I think you are mixing the cherrypy framework and pyramid framework.  Just use cherrypy's wsgi server. Don't do any of the cherrypy configuration.  The last I heard was that Cherrypy was separating out their wsgi server from their framework.  It's been at least a year since I looked.

You might just try using Waitress.  Very good and simple and works across all platforms.

[Openshift-Pyramidstarter](https://github.com/fatfantasma/Openshift-Pyramidstarter)